# Squarespace, Wordpress, or Custom static website for a friend

Tags: wordpress, squarespace

Hey everyone,
A friend of a friend has asked me for help to setup a website. I haven’t really created a website on my own. Although I know HTML, CSS, and Javascript my background has primarily been in Java, Flex, and ActionScript. I don’t mind doing this friend a favor but my time is valuable (New York City is expensive to live in).

**A.** How much should I charge for my valuable time but lack of experience? I was thinking $30/hr or $500 total.

The website would be a static site with 5-10 pages. I’m not sure if the friend (client?) has all the assets (images, layout, styles). I’m just trying to prepare before the meeting in a few days.

**B.** What are my options?

1. Squarespace and similar sites. The client could then figure it out and
   update it without me once the primary project is complete. (I would have to convince the client to leave godaddy though)
2. Setup wordpress with a premium template, customize it (I don’t know
   PHP) and that way the client could
   use the CMS/backend to make future
   revisions. All I’d need are the
   assets.
3. Write it all from scratch? (Could be very time consuming not to mention
   ugly as I’m not a designer)
4. Fourth option?

All opinions are welcome. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: If you say that you're not a designer, then how can you design for the WordPress platform? Charging $30/hour for tweaking someone else's WP theme is IMO borderline scamming ;)

Comment: Blender, I never said I would "design for the wordpress platform". I said I'd get a premium template and then customize it. Those templates are already designed and all one needs to do is edit them through the CMS back-end and perhaps modify some CSS. Also, taking on a project like this will most likely entail management of the site until they are comfortable using the system. And lastly, they asked for me because I'm upfront and don't play games. My time is valuable and if they want me it'll cost at least $30/hr. They can trust me to do a good job and see the project through to the end.

Comment: Exactly my point. You're charging your client to tweak CSS. Not to be rude, but that is like selling free, pre-made WP themes with minor adjustments. And Wordpress is *known/made* for it's 5 minute setup and Ackermann learning curve, so there's not much to teach. Sorry for sounding rude, but I don't endorse selling others' (whether free or paid-for) code as if it were your own. If you're not a designer, then don't design.

Comment: There's no mystery to how I'm doing this. I'm telling them what I'm doing. I'm showing them what's involved. I'm even training them. They know it's not my template. Your view keeps assuming I'm doing and saying things that I'm not telling the client about. The more I understand your view the more I disagree. It's the opportunity cost, their business doesn't involve any technology, they just need the web presence. I invested in knowing how to do this. They invested in other parts of their business. That's how this works. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 3):

I totally see where you're coming from. You're charging for your time, and your time includes CUSTOMISING WordPress. Some people think it's easy. But if you're going into deep-level programming and making more efficient code, then you're really using your expertise in programming and scripting, PHP or otherwise.

I've so much to say in response to Blender, but I guess it's better saving my bytes.

I found myself here cos I'm starting out freelancing now too and I've got a request to create a site, and can quote for a static site's price or to do it on Wordpress. The client already has a design in mind, and I've to go study the Wordpress ins and outs to figure out how to use Wordpress and creating his design as a template. I can use a ready made template that looks similar, but I still will have to spend my time and use my experience as a "purist" HTML/CSS coder with basic Java/ASP knowledge and tweak that template to suit ME.

I am considering $500-$800 for basic setup, and $100-$150 per drill down page. That may sound steep to some, but we find ourselves spending time cleaning up bad logos and cropping photos, as well as doing page layout most of the time. If a work looks too good and simple it means some effort has been put in to make it look effortless. That's what I think anyway when it comes to a clean website, both visually and code-wise.

My prices are in Singapore Dollars, but I guess you can translate the same price to NY, or even more since NY is more expensive!

The point is if your time is worth $30, whether doing dishes or doing programming, then stick to it, cos you know you have to spend time setting up, explaining, discussing and commuting, all factored in. If someone is willing to pay that amount for quality and trust, then no one else should complain.

Comment: And oh, Mr Blender sir, there are companies that actually convert static sites to Wordpress. Because they cost less in the long run to maintain, and add more value. Won't you pay someone a little more to get something better? http://nwtechanddesign.com/blog/2011/06/06/why-you-should-convert-your-website-to-wordpress/

Comment: I've looked around and I think I've found a sort-of market rate as quoted in various forums "Theme should be anywhere from free to $200; professional quality customization would take a minimum of $500."

Answer (score 0):

WP based site with 5-10 static pages and simple design is something around 150-200$ at least we charge somewhere around that.

Comment: Is that for a custom template you make? Or one you find/buy? Does that include touchups to the template and training the client on how to use the CMS?

Comment: It's pretty much custom template as it's based on design. Adding some new stuff later that initially was not planed could require some additional template customization. I don't think there's need for special training besides showing how to change content and do some basic things.